# how to pick images from mobile gallery into an android application

Tags: android, android-layout

how to pick images from gallery into an android application?

I need to browse images form my gallery and choose them for my app .how it can be done ?

Comment: Have a look through the "related" Q&A's on the righthand side of this page - there are several that address your question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use an intent to the gallery (well, "a gallery").

You can find a code example here (I haven't done it but it looks like it will work):
http://www.androidsnippets.com/get-file-path-of-gallery-image

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code:

```
fromGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            //takePhotoFromGallery = true;// edited

                            Intent intent = new Intent(); 
                            intent.setType("image/*"); 
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);// 

                            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),10);

                        }
                    });
```

And then add this:

```
@Override 
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {     
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);     
        if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {             
            Uri contentUri = data.getData();          
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };         
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);         
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);         
            cursor.moveToFirst();         
            imagePath = cursor.getString(column_index);           

            tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath); // this is your image

        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can do this.

In onCreate method

```
    binding.updatephoto.setOnClickListener {
       contract.launch("image/*")
    }
```

After onCreate

```
private val contract = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()){
    it?.let {
        val imageUri = it
    }
}
```